# Android camera is not working with version 6.0.1

Tags: android

Android camera is not working with version 6.0.1.
On capture its crashes. Working properly with lower versions
If anyone know the solution please mention here.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use LogCat to examine the Java stack trace associated with your crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Without a `logcat` I'd assume it's because you aren't requesting run time permissions for the camera/storage.